# MongDb how to count of t null fields and the other one with the count of those with non-null fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

1. The two fields named name_id and age_id respectively. Now I would like to find a document that does not have both two fields and count the total numbers.
2. Below is the code I tried, but it did not work.

   ```
      db.user.aggregate([{ "$group": {
        "_id" : { user_id: "$key_id" },
        "requestA_count": { "$sum": {
            "$cond": [ { "$ifNull": [{"$name_id", false},{"$age_id",false}] }, 1, 0 ]
        } },

       { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "requestA_count": 1,

    } }
    ])
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for. If you want to count docs that have either name_id or age_id simply change `$and` to `$or`.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/cuAVkYnLUTq

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {
    _id: {
      // Group by bool, has both name_id and age_id
      hasIdAndAge: {
        $and: [
          {$toBool: "$name_id"},
          {$toBool: "$age_id"}
        ]
      }
    },
    // Count sum
    count: {$sum: 1}
  }},

  // Rework to only output one object with both counts
  {$group: {
    _id: null,
    has: {
      $sum: {$cond: [
        "$_id.hasIdAndAge", "$count", 0
      ]}
    },
    hasNot: {
      $sum: {$cond: [
        "$_id.hasIdAndAge", 0, "$count"
      ]}
    }
  }}
])

// Outputs
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "has": 1,
    "hasNot": 4
  }
]
```

Comment: but can I use $"$ifNull to find and count both fields not exist?

Comment: You can but there is no need. As you can see in the demo, there are both null and empty values being tested. If you wish to only count null values then I would do ```$and: [{$eq: ["$name_id", null]}, {$eq: ["$age_id", null]}```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `$match` operator seems more fitting. You could do something like this:

```
db.user.aggregate([
    { $match: {$and: [{name_id: null},{age_id: null}]}},
    { $count: "null_name&age"}
])
```

I haven't tested it but that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: What if I do not use $match, how can I use $IfNull to check two fields?

Comment: I can not use $match because I have to find the other two attributes who have the name_id ad age_id, and then count each total number

Comment: How can I use $isNull to check both two fields not exist?

Comment: So you want a result-set with two documents? One with the count of those with null fields and the other one with the count of those with non-null fields? Maybe if you could post the desired output it would be easier to understand the problem.

Comment: yeah, i want a count of those with null fields and the other one with the count of those with non-null fields. I will update the question

Comment: Could you please give me some code or hints? THANK you so much

Comment: You could try to $addFields to add a new boolean field indicating if the fields are null or not and then you could group by that field. After that you would have to count